# Donut chart R with own labels

Tags: r, donut-chart

[image]

Hi, how can I change 1, 2, 3, 4 with own labels?

The code is taken from here:

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/130-ring-or-donut-chart.html

Thanks

Comment: that function has a `labels` argument, so you could try that. otherwise, you can do this in 3 lines: `pie(1:4, labels = 11:14, border = NA); par(new = TRUE); pie(1, labels = '', radius = 0.5, border = NA)`

Comment: Do you need to use base R?  There are a number of visualization packages that simplify the process of creating and customizing a donut chart.